# How to make UI elements in class out of View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, class, cocoa-touch

I'm making app and I'm trying to make a View which contains a Label with a question. I want this view in my app and because I will use it repeatedly, I made a class (If I want to make some change, I can do It from one place). The `UIView` is called `questionView` (`var questionView = UIView()`). Problem is when I want to make `questionView` a subview of `view`. The error says that I don't have have "view" which I understand. I don't have view but how can I get it? Thank you

This is what is inside my Question class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Question {

    // PROPERTIES:

    var questionLabel = UILabel()
    var questionView = UIView()

    // METHODS:

    func createQuestion (input:String) {

        // some code .... not important

        // THIS:
        self.view.addSubview(questionView)

    }

    // ... next code, also not important
}
```

**UPDATE**:

There is my solution. It works BUT I think that it's not correct from a programming standpoint. Can anybody tell me anything about it? Thank you

My class in separate swift file:

My class in separate swift file:

```
class LabelClass {

    var view = UIView()

    init (view: UIView) {
        self.view = view
    }

    var lbl = UILabel()
    var lblView = UIView()

    func makeLabel () {

        self.lbl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 50)
        self.lbl.text = "Text text text"
        self.lbl.numberOfLines = 0

        self.lblView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 150, 50)

        self.lblView.addSubview(self.lbl)
        self.view.addSubview(lblView)

    }

}
```

Piece of code my ViewController.swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Added code:
    var object = LabelClass(view: self.view)
    object.makeLabel()

}
```

Comment: you are calling `self.view`, there is no such property in the class `Question`. If you want it, declare a property called `view` in your class.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Swift, but as far as I know, only instances of `UIViewController` have a `view` property, the class `Question` does not, so you cannot add subviews to it.
What you probably want is making a subclass of `UIView` which contains a question label, or to add the `questionLabel` as a subview of `questionView`.

Comment: Do you know how to make action for these buttons right in class? because if i make "button.addTarget..." in my VC, action is of type String so i cant access it through object. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are trying to add your view to a normal Swift class which doesn't have a self.view instance. Your `Question` class must be a subclass of `UIViewController` cocoa class that it has a self.view instance and override methods.

```
class Question:UIViewController {

    // PROPHERITIES:

    var questionLabel = UILabel()
    var questionView = UIView()

    // METHODS:
    override func viewDidLoad() {
         createQuestion("foo")
    }

    func createQuestion (input:String) {

        // some code .... not important

        // THIS:
        self.view.addSubview(questionView)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // ... next code, also not important
}
```

Comment: I think it would be more reasonable to make a custom `UIView` instead of a custom view controller which would force you to use the controller everytime when actually you only need a `UIView` instance.

Comment: Please check my updated post. I dont know if its correct. It works but maybe it can be done "more correctly". Thank you

Comment: it looks better now, indeed you can extend your LabelClass from UIView class like LabelClass:UIView and you don't need  var view = UIView() variable then. Your LabelClass can be UIView as itself